# Hazelcast multiple embedded instances on one machine

Tags: hazelcast

Is it possible to configure hazelcast so that in one jvm you have a server and a client and have multiple such jvms on one machine where group name is always the same and client always connects to server in the same jvm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible

A JVM can contain more than one instance , client or server

Or have two or more JVMs

You need to check the [Smart Client](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#java-client-operation-modes) mode.

A "smart" client connects to all servers, and uses the "best" connection for each request. So, it has a connection open to all servers, the reverse of what you want.

Set `smartClient` to false and you'll connect to the specified server, which will act as a proxy and retrieve data for that client from other servers if required.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to specify to which server client should connect to. All servers are running on the same machine. So client should simply connect to server in the same jvm as server. Right now when I start several jvms (each with server + client), client on second jvm connects to server from first jvm instead of server in the same jvm

Comment: You can't currently do this. You can connect to all servers concurrently, or a specific one isolation. Perhaps the question here is _why_. Why not move the logic from client to the server you want. You can, for example, run a Java `Callable` on a specific instance.